# Error in micorosoft.xrm.sdk.sample.cs

Tags: c#

I have 30 error from `microsoft.xrm.sdk.sample.cs`, I didn't change anything in the code.

I tried to build xamarin app and get this error message. I already tried to add some reference in my project but the its still show error.

What should I do?

```
using Microsoft.Xrm.Sdk.Metadata.Samples;
using Microsoft.Xrm.Sdk.Query.Samples;
using Microsoft.Xrm.Sdk.Utility.Samples;
using Newtonsoft.Json;      // Used in the REST methods
using Newtonsoft.Json.Linq; // Used in the REST methods
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Collections.ObjectModel;
using System.Collections.Specialized;
using System.Globalization;
using System.IO;
using System.Linq;
using System.Net.Http;
using System.Net.Http.Headers;
using System.Reflection;
using System.Runtime.Serialization.Json;
using System.Text;
using System.Threading.Tasks;
using System.Xml.Linq;
using Windows.ApplicationModel;
```

[image: My Error]

Comment: anyone help please

Comment: Can you post more information on how you got to this point?  Did you clone the whole project? Did you open a solution? (or just a single project file?) Do you have the Xamarin tools installed on your machine?   If you've created your own project, your simplest route might be to open the sample solution and copy all of the references into your project.

Comment: i just follow this tutorial http://scaleablesolutions.com/connecting-xamarin-form-application-with-dynamics-crm/ i follow every step, and still got an error message